# Send pdf document using Gmail with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, email, pdf, gmail

I am trying to send a pdf document through Gmail using VBA.

This code sends email with the pdf attached. When I open the attached pdf, I see a blank page. I can see the size of the pdf is correct, 357kb.

When I manually attach the `pdf` document in Gmail I can see what is inside (not a blank page).

When I attach the file manually, it takes 5 seconds. With the VBA code, the email is sent automatically which might be the reason why I have a blank page. (Gmail does not have enough time to process the document, I guess).

I would love to use Gmail or potentially Windows Mail.

```
Dim Mail As New Message
Dim Config As Configuration
Set Config = Mail.Configuration

Config(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPort
Config(cdoSMTPServer) = "smtp.gmail.com"
Config(cdoSMTPServerPort) = 25
Config(cdoSMTPAuthenticate) = cdoBasic
Config(cdoSMTPUseSSL) = True
Config(cdoSendUserName) = "pchiknagi@gmail.com"
Config(cdoSendPassword) = "XXXXXXXX"
Config.Fields.update

Mail.To = "pchiknagi@gmail.com"
Mail.From = "pchiknagi@gmail.com"
Mail.Subject = "test"
Mail.AddAttachment "c:\temp\sample.pdf"
Mail.Send
```

Comment: In what application are you running this code? Looks like outlook

Comment: I use Excel VBA

Comment: Worth adding excel tag

Comment: just added excel as a tag. I have to say, I have looked every where and I can't find any solution. It probably works with Outlook but I do not have the application

Comment: Well, you must have the Outlook library checked so actually an Outlook tag might be appropriate.

Comment: what will the Outlook library add?

Comment: as my code is focused on gmail

Comment: Do a search for "Email Automation using VBA. Use GMAIL" on YouTube and watch the video, it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I use this as configuration:

```
   'Enable SSL Authentication
   Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
   ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True

   'Make SMTP authentication Enabled=true (1)
   Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
   ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1

   'Set the SMTP server and port Details
   'Get these details from the Settings Page of your Gmail Account
   Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
   ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = _
   "smtp.gmail.com"
   Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
   ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465

   Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
   ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2

   'Set your credentials of your Gmail Account
   Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
   ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = _
   "mymail@gmail.com"
   Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
   ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = _
   "xxxxx"

   'Update the configuration fields
   Mail.Configuration.Fields.Update
```